# how to find a specific letter you want with string inside an array

Tags: c, arrays, string

How would you get an item that contains P or p and returns the number of matches that comes up in this array?

```
            {  SKU:  275, "Royal Gala Apples"   },
            {  SKU:  386, "Honeydew Melon"      },
            {  SKU:  240, "Blueberries"         },
            {  SKU:  916, "Seedless Grapes"     },
            {  SKU:  385, "Pomegranate"         },
            {  SKU:  495, "Banana"              },
            {  SKU:  316, "Kiwifruit"           },
            {  SKU:  355, "Chicken Alfredo"     },
            {  SKU:  846, "Veal Parmigiana"     },
            {  SKU:  359, "Beefsteak Pie"       },
            {  SKU:  127, "Curry Chicken"       },
            {  SKU:  238, "Tide Detergent"      },
            {  SKU:  324, "Tide Liq. Pods"      },
            {  SKU:  491, "Tide Powder Det."    },
            {  SKU:  538, "Lays Chips S&V"      },
            {  SKU:  649, "Joe Org Chips"       },
            {  SKU:  731, "Allen's Apple Juice" },
            {  SKU:  984, "Coke 12 Pack"        },
            {  SKU:  350, "Nestea 12 Pack"      },
            {  SKU:  835, "7up 12 Pack"         }
    };
```

Comment: Look at the man page for strpbrk()... that should get you started... If you still have problems, post your code and ask your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simple solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NPROD 6
struct product {
    int sku;
    char *name;
};

struct product products[NPROD] = {
{  275, "Royal Gala Apples"   },
{  386, "Honeydew Melon"      },
{  240, "Blueberries"         },
{  916, "Seedless Grapes"     },
{  385, "Pomegranate"         },
{  127, "Curry Chickens"      }
};

int main()
{
    int i, j, nfound;
    nfound = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NPROD; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (int)strlen(products[i].name); j++) {
            if (products[i].name[j] == 'p' ||
                products[i].name[j] == 'P') {
                /* Do whathever you want with this product */
                printf("%d %s\n", products[i].sku,
                       products[i].name);
                nfound++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("found %d matching products\n", nfound);
    return 0;
}
```

Also you might use strpbrk() as TonyB suggested replacing the inner for loop with:

```
if (strpbrk("p", products[i].name) ||
    strpbrk("P", products[i].name)) {
    /* Do whathever you want with this product */
    printf("%d %s\n", products[i].sku, products[i].name);
    nfound++;
}
```

However, I am not sure how strbpbrk is implemented but I would not be surprised if it simply performs a for loop for the size of the string. In this case with two calls of strbpbrk this solution would be even less efficient that the first solution. Likely there are better solution but I hope you get the idea. 
This is the output:

```
275 Royal Gala Apples
916 Seedless Grapes
385 Pomegranate
found 3 matching products
```